# Is it possible to schedule and monitor MR and spark jobs using Apache NIFI?

Tags: minify, apache-nifi

I would like to use Apache NiFi for the complete data pipeline scheduling and monitoring for both batch(Map reduce, Hive) and streaming jobs(Spark)

Is it possible to schedule and monitor MR and spark jobs using Apache NIFI?
If it so what are the implementation steps ?

Comment: Yes you can schedule processors by using CRON Expression. What would you do in your MR and spark jobs depends on that only you can monitor it from NiFi.